# run line selection on linux shell script

Tags: linux, shell, vim, geany

I have a day routine shell script as follows

```
#!/bin/bash or whatever

## block1 comments
program1 filepath1 &
program2 filepath2 &

## block1 comments
program3 filepath1 &
program4 filepath2 &
```

Although it does not usually happens, a block can be sometimes more complicated, involving defined variables and unix commands. Each morning I open this file, and all day long what I endup doing is select a block of text, paste into a 'run' script and call it from the terminal ($ ./run.sh)

What I want is to simplify the "select/copy/paste/switch to terminal/run" into "select/run". This is conveniently done in many simple editors. I happen to use Geany, where I don't know how to do this, and I heard Vim can do this, but I don't know how.

If you know other editors that can do this, please drop a line. Many script editors allow you to run a selected text in their associated language interpreter for example. What I want is to run these shell script lines in the terminal, from a simple editor, preferably Geany or Vim.

Comment: Do you run each block back-to-back directly or are there other (non-command) actions that need to happen between lines? Would just splitting that one large file into multiple scripts that you can execute directly work for you?

Comment: My life needs to be simpler than having a daily routine script split into a thousands little scripts, because that would mean looking for the right script. A single file is easier to maintain and it looks clean, I look at it and I simply know what must be done, or what I did. I also hate having to parametrize this script, I just want to select lines and (ideally) hit F5 if you get my meaning.

Comment: You already have to know what block to run. Knowing what script to run doesn't seem meaningfully different to me and avoids the entire copy/paste issue (and associated possible error cases). But if that's not an option (for whatever reason) then a script with arguments is the next best idea and if even *that* isn't an option then you get to see if your editor can script something for you. I'm sure vim and emacs can (depending on if you need to run them in a specific environment or not). I don't know if Geany is capable enough though. An external application could do it via the clipboard.

Comment: this is a great question. I basically want to write shell code like I write R code. Line by line, easily moving around in the script, and testing by hit apple-enter, or f5, or whatever. That design works well with how I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Geany:

Please check `Edit->Commands->Send selection to Terminal`.
You can also assign a keybinding for this. To do so: go to
`Edit->Preferences` and pick the Keybindings tab.

Comment: Thanks, that solved it for Geany, and I tend to favor it to Vim so it is my favored answer. Still, would be curious to see how this could be done in Vim.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to consider using the bash `case` statement:

```
#!/bin/bash -xe
set -x

case $1 in
        thing1)
                echo    T1
        ;;
        thing2)
                echo    T@
        ;;
        *)
                echo "usage ..."
                exit 1
        ;;
esac
```

after this, you should give the command which batch to execute.

`set -x` enables debugging, you may find it useful - or just remove it

Comment: Thanks, I tried this sometime before but it didn't made the document very legible, it complicates things too much, my mind can't recall all these labels, I prefer to keep the script unchanged.